How to identify malicious code on CMS Joomla?
there is a problem on my website https://old.eorccg.ru/ that I noticed back in the first year of 2012, after its creation. There was a situation where I was the only one who visited the site, but at the bottom of the page, in the user line on the site, it already showed over 100 guests. I couldn’t understand what this could be connected with. So now, having launched the site after a long period of inactivity, I see that the situation is beginning to repeat itself.
Today the hosting wrote to me:
Quote
I noticed that one of the scripts was blocked due to Mixed Content (see screenshot), to fix it I added a detective to .htaccess
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
The script began to load, but this did not fix the problem with the cloud.
In addition, not only did it start showing a lot of visitors, but after some time the rest of the sites stopped opening. They suddenly began to show the same material, and when files were deleted, they very quickly reappeared. It feels like I caught some kind of virus. But based on the results of scanning infected files, the hosting company wrote that nothing was detected. The problem may be in malicious code.
Please tell me, is it possible to somehow identify it and fix this problem!?
Haven't tried anything
